# Umbraco surface controller does not work

Tags: routes, umbraco

I've got a site, and it works well on my local computer.

Then I upload it on a server and test it, but the surface controller I called with AJAX can not be routed, and returns 404 status.

My server is Windows Server 2016 Datacenter, and IIS version is 10.

My computer is Windows 10.....

Thanks ~

Comment: Can you show code? Are you calling it with the correct domain?

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution, and the answer is kind of bizzare.
First of all, I tried:

- renaming my controllers namespace from [UmbracoProjectname].Controllers to Controllers  (as seen in SO another post)
- making web.config identical in production as in local server where it works
- updating umbracoReservedPaths with my controller path
- lot of other stuff I forgot at the moment

The solution was this:

Instead of calling

https://domain.tld/umbraco/Surface/CustomSurface/test

I called it this way:

https://domain.tld//umbraco/Surface/CustomSurface/test

(Notice two slashes after domain)

So I guess it was some routing issue, I got it fixed this way. Hope it will help someone else.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible your live (server) site has a different root URL?
Maybe your local is http://localhost/controller but your uploaded live site might be http://www.myserver.com/**myapp**/controller

In that case you will need to check if you are referring to the URL using /controller - and you might have to introduce a setting to indicate the root URL of your site (and you then have a different setting value for each environment).

Comment: I have a same problem as Mark, but I have same root as local. It doesn't help.